# How can I combine two videos in react native so that one video is inside the second video?

Tags: react-native, video, video-processing

I have two separate videos and I want to combine them to one video. Video 2 should then be inside video 1 like this:

[image: Video inside other video]

I tried packages like [react-native-video-processing](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-video-processing), but there it just seems to be able to concatenate them horizontally or vertically, which is not what I want. How can I merge two videos together so that one video is inside the other one in react native?

#### Update:

For simplicity it can be assumed that both videos have the same shape, framerate and format (e.g. MP4). The result should be one video file that contains both videos, where the second overlays the first video.

Comment: _"I tried packages like react-native-video-processing"_ That's overkill just to combine pixels... What happens if you try something basic like using two Video tags to load each video, then use Canvas to combine their pixels at each frame while app is running?

Comment: why not just use absolute positioning to display video 2 over video 1?  Or do you need to save the file?

Comment: I need to save the file

Comment: @Anno **(1)** You need better technical details about the output before anyone can help you. What is your expected output result (for example: a video file has a format, a size, an FPS, etc). Is there anything that someone trying to help you will need to know? _eg: _"The output file must be playable in a HTML5 browser"_ (this way at least your helper now can see that you are trying to get something like an MP4 or WebM or OGV video file).

Comment: @Anno **(2)** Most video encoders expect an image (or pixel) data to make a video frame (picture) so you need to use Canvas to mix your videos. Then WebCodecs, MediaRecorder or a JS-based encoder or check if React Native can use the encoding options the device itself. You need to decide on an output format, try something then ask a new Question about it (possibly delete this one). Follow my first comment then when you have a canvas with frame data and a way to encode (webCodecs? MediaRecorder? other?) I will show you how to step frame-by-frame through the video time to grab/encode each frame.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to display the videos stacked vertically, you could use position: absolute to place the second video on top of the another video. If you also need to save the combined video, you could use the ffmpeg library to combine the videos together, and then display that.

Comment: I looked at [ffmpeg-kit-react-native](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ffmpeg-kit-react-native?activeTab=readme) and can only find ways to concatenate them, but not lay one video on top of the other.